# How to listen broadcast events into vue app from laravel app

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, broadcast, pusher

I'm making an app with 2 different frameworks, **Laravel 5.5** and **Vuetify 1.5** (**Vuejs 2.0**). Now I'm trying to make broadcast events dispatched from laravel app using **pusher** and to make vuetify project listen it but... There is the problem.

My intention is to create service worker to listen the private channel and dispatch local notification on listen that event. But I couldn't do the first step, to listen the event.

- **How can I listen events dispatched from private channel by laravel app from another javascript framework?**

Comment: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting

Comment: I read the laravel docs of broadcasting 3 or 4 times today. The problem is that I'm trying to listen private channel, and to do this I need to authenticate. But I will try to use socketio and public channel because now I'm using pusher with private channel.

Comment: Did you try [laravel echo server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server)? It supports auth and private channels. Uses socket.io also.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I will try it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### VueJs

```
  window.Echo.channel("channel-name").listen(".channel-app", e => {
    console.log(e);
 });
```

---

### Laravel

#### Event

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new Channel('channel-name');
}

public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'channel-app';
}
```

#### Controller

```
public function test()
{
    broadcast(new MessageSent());
}
```

#### channel

```
Broadcast::channel('channel-name', function(){ return true; });
```

Comment: where will I put this channel "Broadcast::channel('channel-name', function(){ return true; });"